# What is difference between $\cup\emptyset =\emptyset$ and $\cup$ {$\emptyset$}$ =\emptyset$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

What is difference between $\cup\emptyset =\emptyset$ and $\cup$ {$\emptyset$}$ =\emptyset$.

Also What is $\cup$ {$\mathbb{R}$}$ =\mathbb{R}$ mean?.

Comment: The first line lists two ways to obtain the empty set and the 2nd line is true by the mere definition of $\bigcup$. Since this can't possibly be the answer you are looking for, I have no idea what your actual question is.

Comment: Where did you see this notation? Usually you would write something like $A \cup B$ for a binary union, or $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ for a union of sets $A_i$ indexed by some set $I$.

Comment: I guess it's union of all elements of the set

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ its not an uncommon notation. I mean it is explicitly part of the most common axiomatisation see [Axiom of Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union).

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ I saw from definiton of open set.

Comment: They are both the null set but for different reasons: the first uses the relatively unused nullary union whilst the second uses a unary union on an empty set.

Comment: Perhaps some generality will help: Consider what addition or multiplication over a finite set of real numbers would mean. The union is being used in a similar way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the notation "$\bigcup\mathcal{A}$" means "The set of all things which are an element *of an element* of $\mathcal{A}$."

- If $\mathcal{A}$ is empty, it has no elements, so it certainly has no elements-of-elements; so $\bigcup \emptyset=\emptyset$.
- What if $\mathcal{A}=\{\emptyset\}$? Then $\mathcal{A}$ does indeed have an element . . . but that element has no elements. So there are *still* no "elements of elements of $\mathcal{A}$", so $\bigcup\{\emptyset\}=\emptyset$.
- Now $\bigcup\{\mathbb{R}\}$ means "the set of all things which are elements of $\mathbb{R}$." This is just $\mathbb{R}$! So indeed we have $\bigcup\{\mathbb{R}\}=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So,  $\bigcup\mathbb{R}$ is equal to $\mathbb{R}$ , isn't it?

Comment: @Kahler **No, it is not**. $\bigcup\mathbb{R}$ is the set of elements of *elements of* $\mathbb{R}$. So: what are the elements of $2$? of $\pi$? etc. At this point it depends how exactly we treat "$\mathbb{R}$" in set theory (a set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences? a set of Dedekind cuts?), but in every formalization I'm aware of arbitrary real numbers are *not* elements of real numbers.